# Correcting Time Format in R

Tags: r

I have a column of timestamp from a race; the time logs are given either in HH:MM:SS format or MM:SS format. I need to convert them from character to time format; I will be using as.POSIXct but first I am having issues dealing with the observations where the format is MM:SS as opposed to HH:MM:SS. When I apply as.POSIXct to the column, I get an error because all the observations don't have the same format. How do I add the "00:" leading up to a "59:34" timestamp?

Time
"59:34"
"32:07"
"1:08:06"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `lubridate::hms`. If you want to use `as.POSIXct`, substitute your code for that.

It assumes that all values are either MM:SS or HH::MM::SS.

`ts1` is the original values, `ts2` pre-pended with "00:" where necessary and `ts3` the final values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

data.frame(ts1 = c("59:34", "32:07", "1:08:06")) %>% 
  mutate(ts2 = ifelse(str_count(ts1, ":") == 1, paste0("00:", ts1), ts1), 
         ts3 = hms(ts2))
```

Result:

```
      ts1      ts2      ts3
1   59:34 00:59:34  59M 34S
2   32:07 00:32:07   32M 7S
3 1:08:06  1:08:06 1H 8M 6S
```

Comment: I have a slight issue; last night the code worked just fine, but today I am getting this error: "Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `ts3`.
i `ts3 = hms(ts2)`.
x All arguments must be numeric or NA"

Comment: gun <- data.frame(ts1 = male.data$Gun.Tim) %>%
  mutate(ts2 = ifelse(str_count(ts1, ":") == 1, paste0("00:", ts1), ts1),
         ts3 = hms(ts2))  <<< This is how I built my code; gun.Tim is my time vector.

Comment: Would need to see the data in `gun` to help. Code works with example data in the question.

Answer (score 3):

A base R option -

```
x <- c("59:34", "32:07", "1:08:06")
as.POSIXct(ifelse(nchar(x) > 5, x, paste0('00:', x)), format = '%T', tz = 'UTC')

#[1]"2021-11-24 00:59:34 UTC" "2021-11-24 00:32:07 UTC" "2021-11-24 01:08:06 UTC"
```

Since there is no date in the data `as.POSIXct` appends todays date.

Comment: Interesting. I have tried that second line you provided here. But w/out the format and timezone. What does the format do?

Comment: `format` is used to provide the input format your data is in. `as.POSIXct` expects `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format but since our input is in different format we need to specify that separately. `%T` is used when you have data in `HH:MM:SS` format. More details of different formats in `?strptime`.